# CSS Adjustment Not Working for Some Divs

Tags: css

I'm having trouble locating which CSS code to adjust in order to lower down the 2nd row of image thumbnails on this page: http://www.criminal-lawyers.com.au/ebooks-other-legal-resources.

All thumbnails are under the class `img_thumb`. Initially, they were all scattered and I had to adjust the CSS codes related to this class in order to lower them down so that they rest exactly on the line. So I adjusted the top margin. But doing this only corrected the position of the thumbnails on the first row, but not the position of those on the second row. How do I adjust the 2nd row without affecting the first row?

I could create a class for each thumbnail then adjust from there but is there a way for me not to do that? I'm thinking maybe I'm just missing out an important element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the height to 185px of this div

```
.bs_product.sk03_md {
float: left !important;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-top: 100px !important;
height: 185px;   
position: relative !important;
display: block;
direction: ltr !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I am glad to help